# how to force the new design on PayPal Payments Standard?

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal Payments Standard for payments, with a POST form to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr . I noticed that PayPal started rolling out a new design and found some questions of people trying to force the old design instead of the new one. Well, I want it the other way around..

I want this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

is that at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no control over the layout that you can force to show up . Currently it depends on various factors like IP address , buyer / seller country and etc . Once the rolling out is done completely you will be seeing the new layout only .

Comment: That sucks :( But makes sense. Thank you :)